# How to check a dictionary value to see if it is equal to something GDSCRIPT

Tags: conditional-statements, godot, gdscript

I have some code that determines if the player has bought something or not in the store. I want to give that player the item if any of the values == true

```
var store = {
    'bought' : [false, false, false, false, false, false],
    'purchased': 0,
}
```

i was trying something like if (store[bought[1]]) == true but i suck at coding so it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have a dictionary named `store`. And it has a `'bought'` key that you can read, like this:

```
var bought = store['bought']
```

Or like this:

```
var bought = store.bought
```

And that key is associated with an array, that you can index, like this:

```
var bought = store['bought']
var item = bought[0]
```

Or like this:

```
var bought = store.bought
var item = bought[0]
```

Or, if you don't want to take `bought` in a separate variable, you should be able to access it like this:

```
var item = store['bought'][0]
```

Or like this:

```
var item = store.bought[0]
```

Comment: i did it by doing if Global.store.bought[1] == true: